# Name for region of plane bounded by two rays?

Tags: terminology

Is there a name for e.g. the locus $$\pi/6 \leq \arg z \leq \pi/3$$ on an Argand diagram?

(Perhaps something analogous to a [half-plane](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Half-Plane.html)?)

Answer (score 1):

In French and Spanish, this is named, literally translated "**angle sector**".

However, considering all the plane, if the angle is not well defined (orientation, etc) two right lines define four angle sectors as it is obvious.In your example the angle sector is correctly defined.

Answer (score 0):

I think that "angle" is the correct term, actually!

Answer (score 0):

An [angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle), perhaps? Mathworld says the angle is rather 'an amount of rotation', but Wikipedia calls that an 'angle measure'...